# Groovy Elvis, how does this works in Elvis?

Tags: groovy

From Groovy point of view Elvis operator(`?:`) is used to return the value of the left expression if its evaluates to `true`, but the value of the right expression otherwise. But what happens if the code is like this:

> age <=> other.age ?: lastName <=> other.lastName ?: firstName <=>
>   other.firstName

How does it executes the above code?

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN2535-Control, `<=>` has higher precedence than `?:`. This means that...

```
age <=> other.age ?: lastName <=> other.lastName ?: firstName <=> other.firstName
```

becomes something like...

```
0 ?: -1 ?: 0
```

which ends up as -1. Since `0 ?: -1 == -1` and `-1 ?: 0 == -1`.

Hope that makes sense. Looks like the example is meant to be used to carry out sorting on age, then last name, then first name.

Comment: `0 ?: -1 == -1` this becomes -1 because the left part becomes `false`(zero) but how does `-1 ?: 0 == -1` this becomes -1?

Comment: @tim : Oh! is that useful to make -1 as true in Groovy.. Whats the real need?

Comment: @Ant's - Well, think of it as any number that is *not* zero is `false`, which is all negative numbers.  (At first, I didn't like the shorthand in the original question, but once you recognize it, it's a really clean way to write sorting rules.)

Answer (score 2):

So with Groovy, `0` is considered false

What that line is doing is comparing `age` to `other.age` and if they are the same (`0`) then comparing `lastName` to `other.lastName`, etc...

So, this will return the order of things based on several properties in order of precedence

Answer (score 1):

It compares first by age, then by last name, then by first name, short-circuiting on the first nonzero comparison result. If you use the result to sort then it will sort by age, then within that by last name, then within that by first name.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a specific reference on the operator precedence, but a simple experiment using groovyconsole (as well as my personal experience using them in the same way that you listed) is that the spaceship operator (<=>) and elvis operator (?:) have equal precedence and are thus interpreted left-to-right.  For your example, the result is simply:

```
  -1 if age < other.age
   1 if age > other.age
   else (age = other.age)
      -1 if lastName < other.lastName
       1 if lastName > other.lastName
       else (age = other.age && lastName == other.lastName)
          -1 if firstName < other.lastName
           1 if firstName > other.firstName
           0 (all three comparisons are equal)
```